# Black Screen Appearing in PivitItem Sliding Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am working on windows phone 8.1 WinRT app

Black Screen Appearing in how we PivitItem Sliding , how can slide image one before another in Pivot or in same control like slider in web forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used FlipView and its solve my problem